# Integral of limit of pointwise convergent sequence of non-negative measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose $\{f_n\} \subset L^+$ , $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise, and $\int f = \lim \int f_n < \infty$. Then $\int_{E} f = \lim \int_{E} f_n$ for all $E \in \mathcal{M}$. However, this needn't be true if $\int f = \lim \int f_n = \infty$.

This is the exercise 13 on page 52, *Real Analysis*, by Gerald B. Folland. $L^+$ is the space of all measurable functions from $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ to $[0, \infty]$.

I can find a counterexample satisfying $\int f = \lim \int f_n = \infty$. Let $X = \Bbb N$, $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$ and $\mu$ be the counting measure. $f_n = \chi_{\{2i+1:i \leq n\} \cup \{2j:n \leq j \leq 2n \}}$. Then $\int f = \lim \int f_n = \infty$. But when $E = \{2k: k \in \Bbb N\}$,  Then $\int_{E} f =  0$ and $\lim \int_{E} f_n = \infty$.

But how to show the part "$f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise, and $\int f = \lim \int f_n < \infty$. Then $\int_{E} f = \lim \int_{E} f_n$ for all $E \in \mathcal{M}$"?

Comment: Fatou's lemma, I would say.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Thank you. I think I got it now. $\int_{E} f < \lim \int_{E} f_n$ implies that $\int_{E^c} f > \lim \int_{E^c} f_n$, which contradicts with Fatou's lemma. Please consider posting your hint as answer.

Comment: Doing that right now.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace, in your counterexample, I think $f=\chi_{\mathbb{N}}$. So, $\lim \int_E f_n=\infty$ because $ \int_E f_n=n+1$. But I couldn't conclude $ \int_E f=0$. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By Fatou's lemma, you have

$$\begin{align}
\infty &> \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n\\
&= \int f\\
&= \int_E f + \int_{X\setminus E} f\\
&\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_E f_n + \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{X\setminus E} f_n\\
&\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_E f_n + \int_{X\setminus E} f_n\right)\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int f_n\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n,
\end{align}$$

so the inequalities here are actually equalities, and

$$\int_E f = \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_E f_n$$

for all $E\in\mathcal{M}$. Now if we had $\limsup \int_E f_n > \int_E f$ for some $E\in\mathcal{M}$, selecting a subsequence with $\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_E f_{n_k} > \int_E f$ would for that subsequence force

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_{X\setminus E} f_{n_k} = \int f - \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_E f_{n_k} < \int f - \int_E f = \int_{X\setminus E} f,$$

contradicting Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Dear @Daniel, it's clear to me that the inequalities here are actually equalities, but I couldn't derive the equality $\int_E f=\lim \inf \int_E f_n$. May you help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @rgm We have a chain of inequalities $L = a + b \leqslant c + d \leqslant L$. Here $a = \int_E f$, $b = \int_{X\setminus E} f$, $c = \liminf \int_E f_n$, and $d = \liminf \int_{X\setminus E} f_n$. Since $L = \int_X f = \lim \int_X f_n$ is a real number, this implies $a + b = L = c + d$. By Fatou's lemma, we have $a \leqslant c$ and $b \leqslant d$, and thus it follows that $a = c$ and $b = d$, for if we had e.g. $a < c$ it would follow that $$0 = L - L = (c+d) - (a+b) = (c - a) + (d - b) \geqslant c - a > 0\,,$$ which is absurd.